# Page with fixed centered layout, scrollbar shifts position of the content

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, css-position

I have this layout (simplified)

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="header">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I need the header and footer to be fixed while keeping the content scrollable. Problem is that all 3 are centered and if I set `#content {overflow-y: scroll;}` and scrollbar appears, the whole content of `<div id="content">` is shifted to the left and isn't in line with header and footer. Is there a way to prevent it? Or maby some workaround?

EDIT: [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zABUR/2/).

Comment: Can you put the CSS code? It would be good a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want?

I made it with Flexbox, but if you don't wanna use a box model under revision, I could do this with `display: table`, for example.

DEMOs:

1. [Layout with Flexbox](http://jsfiddle.net/Jqr2p/1/)
2. [Layout with `display: table`](http://jsfiddle.net/Jqr2p/2/)

**

### What I've done?

**

**First demo: Layout with Flexbox**

In this demo I only add the follow classes in the `body` element:

```
<body class="p-flexbox flex-vcc">
 <!-- The rest of your content -->
</body>
```

Where:

1. **p-flexbox** means *parent-flexbox*.
2. **flex-vcc** means *flexbox-vertical-center-center*

And the follow CSS rules:

```
.p-flexbox {
    /* Flexbox: Init setup */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
}
.flex-vcc {
    /* Flexbox: Principal setup */
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    box-pack: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    box-align: center;
}
```

What means this? It means that all the body's children will center to the vertical axis and will center in the another axis (x axis).

Besides, I change a bit your CSS code adding sizes to a few elements.

**Second demo: Layout with `display: table`**

`display: table` is a good way to make the layout in a web page. Before, web developers made  the layout with `table` elements (in the markup). This wasn't a good practice because the tables are only for tabular data. But if you use `display: table` in the style, you will obtain the same result that if you make the layout using `table` elements in the markup.

For do that, you only add the follow classes to the "*container*" element (in my case, `div.principal`):

```
div.principal {
   display: table;
}
```

This means that the `div.principal` will behave like a `table` element. With this you can add the same properties that a table!

For example: `border-collapse`, `border-spacing`, etc.

Well, that's it.

Cheers,
Leonardo

Comment: Great answer but it doesn't take the `position: fixed;` thing into account. Anyway, why do you set `display: table-cell` for the `#content`?